# Simulating poor network connections in Busybox

Tags: android, networking, iptables, busybox

I am writing a script to simulate poor network connections for an Android device using Busybox. In Bash, I am using `tc` and `netem` to simulate packet loss, specific latencies, etc., but these are not available in Busybox. I know that Busybox has `iptables` available, but it does not offer as much functionality as `netem`. I have a few questions:

1. How do you suggest simulating poor network connections in Busybox? I have done quite a bit of research and haven't found anyone who has tried testing slow connections to a device with Busybox.
2. Is there a way to compile `netem` for Busybox, and could you point me in the right direction to get started with that if it is possible?
3. Is there a way to simulate specific latencies, packet loss, corruption, and duplication with `iptables`, as is possible with `netem`?

Thanks.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with bash

Comment: I am trying to find an equivalent function of `netem` to use in Busybox, which is available in bash. The script I am writing is in bash, and I'd like to move it to another device

Comment: best to remove the bash tag to satisfy the purists ;-) . Did you read  the BusyBox doc? What you need (in the larger picture) is to add `tc` and/or `netem` as a BusyBox applet. Unspecific instructions are here, but seem doable :  https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#adding . I also found this page to be a good overview of how BusyBox distributions are constructed : https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html .  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find `tc` (as well as other network utilities) in `busybox/networking`.

Check https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/busybox/blob/master/networking/tc.c

It's not clear form your question if you are doing it on an android device or on another device. In any case, you may have to recompile busybox for your target if `tc` is not enabled.